# Java HttpServlet, override method service, best practice

Tags: java, servlets

For logging purposes, I override the service method from HttpServlet like this:

```
@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
{
    logger.debug("enter servlet");
    logger.debug("Request Header: {}", MyHttpTools.requestHeaderToSting(req);

    super.service(req, resp);

    logger.debug("leaving servlet");
    logger.debug("Response Header: {}", MyHttpTools.responseHeaderToSting(resp);
}
```

I found some places in the web, where authors say "don't override service".

What do you think of my approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing inherently wrong with your approach.

The authors are saying that don't override `service()` for business code, override the `doPost()`, `doGet()` etc. methods instead.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with your approach, but you could do it in a "cleaner" (in my opinion) way, e.g. by implementing (and registering) a `javax.servlet.Filter`, or by using AspectJ, or other approaches that are more commonly used.

Comment: thank you, I'll take a look at AspectJ. I already use filters with URL mapping in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct. You can do logging with aspectJ too.

Answer (score 0):

> The default service() method in an HTTP servlet routes the request to another method based on the HTTP transfer method (POST, GET, and so on). For example, HTTP POST requests are routed to the doPost() method, HTTP GET requests are routed to the doGet() method, and so on. This enables the servlet to perform different request data processing depending on the transfer method. **Since the routing takes place in service(), there is no need to generally override service() in an HTTP servlet**. Instead, override doGet(), doPost(), and so on, depending on the expected request type.

For detail plz go through this article : [Sun Java System Web Server 6.1 SP6 Programmer's Guide to Web Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19857-01/819-6518/abxbe/index.html)